# Presentation $\langle x,y,z\mid xyx^{-1}y^{-2},yzy^{-1}z^{-2},zxz^{-1}x^{-2}\rangle$ of group equal to trivial group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, group-presentation

> **Problem:** Show that the group given by the presentation $$\langle x,y,z  \mid xyx^{-1}y^{-2}\, , \, yzy^{-1}z^{-2}\, , \, zxz^{-1}x^{-2} \rangle $$ is equivalent to the trivial group.

I have tried all sorts of manners to try to show that the relations given by the presentation above imply that $x=y=z=e$. However, I am stuck and would appreciate any hints as to how I should move forward.

Comment: Do you know any reference where you found this question. I saw it in previous year question paper of my institution.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a very well-known presentation of the trivial group, to be compared with the presentation of [Higman's infinite group with no finite quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman_group). I do not know of any easy proof.

The proof I'm going to give is due to [Bernhard Neumann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Neumann) in *An Essay on Free Products of Groups with Amalgamations* (Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London, Series A, **246**, 919 (1954), pp. 503-554.)

So we have to prove that in a group satisfying 
$$ xyx^{-1} = y^2 \qquad (R_1)$$
$$ yzy^{-1} = z^2 \qquad (R_2)$$
$$ zxz^{-1} = x^2 \qquad (R_3)$$
the elements $x$, $y$ and $z$ are trivial.

By inverting $(R_1)$, multiplying on the left by $y$ and on the right by $x$, we get $$yxy^{-1} = y^{-1}x.$$ This easily gives $$y^i x y^{-i} = y^{-i} x \qquad(R_1^{[i]}),$$ for every integer $i$, by induction. The same argument on the second relation gives $$z^i y z^{-i} = z^{-i} y. \qquad (R_2^{[i]})$$

If we now conjugate $(R_3)$ by $y$, the left-hand side becomes
$$\begin{align}yzxz^{-1}y^{-1} &= z^2y\cdot x \cdot y^{-1}z^{-2}\\
& = z^2y^{-1}xz^{-2}\\
& = z^2 y^{-1}z^{-2}\cdot z^2xz^{-2}\\
& = y^{-1}z^2\cdot x^4
\end{align}$$
(the first equality is a double use of the relation $yz = z^2y$, a reformulation of $(R_2)$ ; the second uses $(R_1^{[1]})$ and the last uses the inverse of $(R_2^{[2]})$ and $R_3$ twice).

On the other hand, the left side becomes
$$\begin{align} yx^2y^{-1} &= (y^{-1}x)^2 \\
&= y^{-1}xy^{-1}x \\
&= y^{-3}x^2
\end{align}$$
(the first equality uses the $(R_1^{[1]})$ twice, the last uses the inverse of $(R_1)$).

Put together, we have proven $y^{-1}z^2x^4 = y^{-3}x^2$, which gives
$$z^2 = y^{-2}x^{-2}.\qquad (R^*)$$

If we conjugate $y$ by $z^{-2}$, we now get on the one hand
$$\begin{align}z^{-2}y z^2 &= x^2 y^2 \cdot y \cdot y^{-2} x^{-2} \\
&= x^2 y x^{-2} \\
&= y^4
\end{align}$$
(the first equality uses $(R^*)$ twice, the last uses $(R_1)$ twice.) But, on the other hand, $z^{-2}yz^2 = z^2 y$ because of $(R_2^{[-2]}$). So we finally get $z^2 y = y^4$, which translates to
$$z^2 = y^3.$$

This proves that $y$ and $z^2$ commute. The relation $(R_2)$ then boils down to $z = z^2$, which gives $z = 1$. Because of the symmetries in the presentation, this proves that the group is trivial.

Not very enlightening, but the fact that the corresponding group with 4 generators is highly nontrivial somehow reduces my hopes of ever finding a "good reason" for this group to be trivial.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a proof-

$G=\langle x,y,z  \mid xyx^{-1}=y^{2}\, , \, yzy^{-1}=z^{2}\, , \, zxz^{-1}=x^{2} \rangle$. See that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=y$ tells you that $y$ belongs in the Commutator subgroup generated by $x$ and $y$ and similarly $x$ belongs in Commutator subgroup generated by $x$ and $z$ and $z$ belongs in Commutator subgroup generated by $z$ and $y$ and Now this gives you that $G$ is perfect i.e. $G=G'$. Now If you can prove $G$ is solvable , you are done as only perfect solvable group is trivial group.

So consider the subgroup generated by $H=\langle x,y \rangle$ and show that $H$ is solvable. For that consider $H_1=\langle y \rangle < H$ and it is easily seen that $H_1 \unlhd\ H$ so what is factor group $H/H_1$? Yeah correct, $H/H_1\ \cong\ \langle x \rangle$ which is abelian and hence $H$ is solvable.

Now only thing remains is to check that $H=G$, i.e. $z \in \langle x,y \rangle$. Now is the tedious calculation work you will have to do, in order to prove this, use the relators given and express $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

I hope this helps!