Proving that a group is infinite and nonabelian
As an exercise I am trying to prove that the group $$G = \langle a,b,c \mid ac = ba, ab=ca,  bc=ab\rangle$$ is infinite and non-abelian. Moreover, the author claims that its center has finite index.
I have tried to find a group which is (a subgroup of) this abstract group, but to no advance. I have seen similar posts on the forum, but their answers were rather specific to the considered group, and did not provide a general approach.

I don't think you should begin by looking for subgroups, but rather look for quotients. I (no expert) would start  by investigating $G/G'$, that is looking to see what  happens if $a,b,c$ commute. That would at least show that $G$ was infinite.

$G$ is infinite, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is its quotient, by adding $a=b=c$ relationship. Showing that it is nonabelian seems harder though.

Try showing that $S_3$ is a quotient.

Send  $G\mapsto S_3,$ the symmetry group on $3$ elements, with $a\mapsto(12), b\mapsto(13), c\mapsto (23).$

I think that there is no general approach. The word problem for groups is undecidable. Though of course there are simple sufficient conditions for a group being infinite, e.g. if it can be shown that one of the generators has infinite order.

In fact the subgroup $\langle a^2\rangle$ is central, and you can show the quotient is $S_3$.

You've already gotten an answer, but I wanted to discuss the structure of $G$ a bit more. The first relation allows you to write $b=aca^{-1}$, so you can remove the generator $b$ by simply replacing each occurrence with the above word, to get the presentation
\begin{equation}
G\cong\langle a,c\mid [a^2,c]=1, [a,c^{-1}]=c^{-1}a\rangle
\end{equation}
This shows $a^2\in Z(G)$. From the general fact $[a^2,c^{-1}]=[a,c^{-1}]^a[a,c^{-1}]$, in our group this shows (using the above relations) that $a^2=c^{2}$. So
\begin{equation}
G/\langle a^2\rangle\cong \langle a,c\mid a^2=c^2=1, [a,c^{-1}]=c^{-1}a\rangle
\end{equation}
Because $a\equiv a^{-1}$ and $c\equiv c^{-1}$ in this quotient, that last relation is equivalent to $(ac)^3=1$. So $G/\langle a^2\rangle$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $6$, otherwise known as $S_3$. Because $Z(S_3)=\{1\}$, we also know $Z(G)=\langle a^2\rangle$.
We can even give a full description of the structure of $G$. Because $G/G'\cong\mathbb{Z}$ (a free group), we actually have $G\cong G'\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$. Since $[G:Z(G)]$ is finite, we also know $G'$ is finite. Because $G$ is non-Abelian and $G'$ maps to $A_3\le S_3\cong G/Z(G)$, it must be that $G'\cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, so that
\begin{equation}
G\cong (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})\rtimes \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}
with the generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ acting via inversion.
This semidirect product structure can also be seen from the presentation. Let $d=c^{-1}a$. Then the relation $[a,c^{-1}]=c^{-1}a$ can be rewritten as $d^2=ada^{-1}$. The relation $[a^2,c]=1$ can similarly be rewritten as $[a^2,d]=1$. So $G$ has presentation
\begin{equation}
G\cong\langle a,d\mid [a^2,d]=1, ada^{-1}=d^2\rangle
\end{equation}
From these relations we derive
\begin{equation}
d^4 = ad^2a^{-1} = a^2da^{-2} = d
\end{equation}
so that $d^3=1$. Our new presentation $\langle a,d\mid d^3=1, ada^{-1}=d^{-1}\rangle$ is exactly our semidirect product.

Its abelianisation is
$$\langle a,b,c\mid a=b=c\rangle^{{\rm ab}}\cong \Bbb Z$$
and $G\twoheadrightarrow S_3$ (see the comments).

Why the downvote?

Taking some observations from the comments, define the homomorphism:
$$f:G\to \Bbb Z\;,\;\;f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=1$$
and extend accordingly to any word in $\;a,b,c\;$ in $\;G\;$ (thus, the image of any element (reduced word) in $\;G\;$ will just be the number of  not-cancelling-in-the-image-of-$\;f\;$-letters (since for example  $\;f(ab^{-1})=f(a)+f(b)^{-1}=1+(-1)=0\;$)
Observe that $\;\text{Im}\,f=\Bbb Z\;$ since
$$\forall\,n\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;f(a^n)=nf(a)=n$$
and thus $\;G\;$ is infinite
Now, if $\;G\;$ were abelian then
$$ac\stackrel{\text{given}}=ba=ab\stackrel{\text{given}}=bc\implies ac=bc\implies a=b$$
and then likewise
$$a^2=ab\stackrel{\text{given}}=ca\implies a=c$$
and thus $\;a=b=c\;$ , which are precisely the relations added to the group to get the above quotient ...
In the times I read the books by Solitar, Karrass and Magnus, or the Lyndon & Schupp, etc. there was a somewhat vivid discussion within the Group Theory kernel in the faculty about how must a group's presentation be understood. For example, in your group we MUST assume that $\;a,b,c\;$ are all different unless it can be proved by the given relations that the group is the trivial one, which in itself can be a rather complex and interesting task.
I can't know under what assumptions you work but hopefully the above answer can at least give you some ideas.

$f$ is not an endomorphism. Maybe you mean epimorphism.

A group presentation has a precise definition as a quotient of a free group. Your statement "we MUST assume that ,, are all different unless it can be proved by the given relations that the group is the trivial one" doesn't work because, for example, the group $\langle a,b,c \mid a=b \rangle$ is nontrivial, but the generators $a$ and $b$ are equal (or to be precise they represent the same element of the group defined by the presentation). The easiest way to prove that the group here is nonabelian is to show that it has an epimorphism onto the group $S_3$, as indicated in the comments.

@LukasHeger  Of course you're right, Lukas. Thanks, edited.

@DerekHolt Thanks. I might be forgetting something right now, but back then in graduate school it was a rather confusing subject and, in your example say, some would claim that $;b;$ should be just scratched from that presentation unless, of course, we'd be referring to a homomorphic image of the free group in three letters and we'd use those letter to give the presentation. I guess I should go on this subject once again. It was very interesting.

The problem with this topic is that questions like is $a=b$, or is this group defined by the presentation  trivial are provably undecidable for general group presentations, so you can't expect to make any assumptions of the type you are suggesting.

@DonAntonio there are situation where it isn't obvious that some properties arise from other. For example this group: $\langle x,y,z  \mid xyx^{-1}=y^{2}, , , yzy^{-1}=z^{2}, , , zxz^{-1}=x^{2} \rangle$ is trivial as you can see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134410/show-that-the-group-is-trivial In particular $x=y=z=1$ follows from the presentation. But is it obvious that you can "scrach out" all the generators? And it is only slightly different from the presentation here. In other words, it is the opposite: you cannot assume that $a,b,c$ are all different.
