# Some commutator identities

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

On the way to study Lang's algebra, I cannot solve this problem. See page 69.

Let G be a group and denote the commutator of x and y by & $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$. 
I wanna prove that if $[x,y]=y, [y,z]=z, [z,x]=x$ then $x=y=z=e$.

I tried before posting it, but I don't have a clue. Please give me some hints or solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are $x$, $y$ and $z$ arbitrary? Then letting $x = e$ in the first commutator yields $y = e$.In a similar fashion we will have $z = e$ from the second and and $x = e$ from the third.

Comment: Yeah, then if all of them were not identity, how to prove it?

Comment: Hint: rewrite these as conjugation identities (so y conjugated by x is y^2). Use this to get a finite order for x, then y, then z. Use the finite order of z to get *another* finite order for x, and use the two orders of x to show its trivial.

Comment: Actually, I see an easier way to approach this: the three subgroup lemma shows xyz=1. From here it is easy to show one (and hence all) the generators are trivial.

Comment: @Steve D: I doubt whether the OP will be aware of the three subgroup lemma.

Comment: I didn't see how three subgroup lemma will be applicable to this problem.

Comment: @pGroups: Sorry, I meant the Hall-Witt identity.  I added an answer explaining the approach.

Answer (score 3):

Writing commutator identities explicitly gives 
$$xyx^{-1}=y^2, yzy^{-1}=z^2, zxz^{-1}=z^2.$$
It appeared [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023341/presentation-of-group-equal-to-trivial-group), in similar way, that a group $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ with these relations is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I outlined in the comments above.

From the identity $[x,y]=y$, one sees that $xyx^{-1} = y^2$.  I will write $y^x$ from now on, for $xyx^{-1}$; similarly, I write ${}^xy$ for $x^{-1}yx$.

We also see from this commutator relation that ${}^yx=yx$ and $x^y=y^{-1}x$. Similar identities can be deduced from the other two commutator relations.

So a quick check shows $[x,y^{-1}]=y^{-1}$, and so

\begin{align}
[[x,y^{-1}],z] &= y^{-1}(zyz^{-1}) \\
&= y^{-1}z^{-1}y
\end{align}

(The second equality comes from $y^z=z^{-1}y$). This means that
$$ [x,y^{-1},z]^y=z^{-1} $$
Similarly, we get
$$ [y,z^{-1},x]^z = x^{-1} $$
and
$$ [z,x^{-1},y]^x = y^{-1} $$

The [Hall-Witt identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_subgroups_lemma#Proof_and_the_Hall.E2.80.93Witt_identity) then shows $z^{-1}x^{-1}y^{-1}=1$, or
$$ z = x^{-1}y^{-1} $$

Let's put that value for $z$ into the final commutator relation; we get

\begin{align}
x &= [z,x] \\
&= [x^{-1}y^{-1},x] \\
&= x^{-1}y^{-1}xyxx^{-1} \\
&= x^{-1}(y^{-1}xy) \\
&= x^{-1}yx
\end{align}

(The last equality comes from ${}^yx=yx$).  Conjugating both sides by $x$ shows $x=y$.  Thus $y=[x,y]=1$, and hence $x=y=1$, and so $z=1$ as well; the group is trivial.