# Please tell me what the author wants to say. ("Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I N. Herstein)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, automorphism-group

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
The following sentences are in this book.
I cannot understand what the author wants to say:

> Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $7$, that is, $G$ consists of all $a^i$, where we assume $a^7=e$. The mapping $\phi:a^i\to a^{2i}$, as can be ckecked trivially, is an automorphism of $G$ of order $3$, that is $\phi^3=I$. Let $x$ be a symbol which we formally subject to the following conditions: $x^3=e,x^{-1}a^ix=\phi(a^i)=a^{2i}$, and consider all formal symbols $x^ia^j$, where $i=0,1,2$ and $j=0,1,2,\dots,6$. We declare that $x^ia^j=x^ka^l$ if and only if $i\equiv k\mod 3$ and $j\equiv l\mod 7$. We multiply these symbols using the rules $x^3=a^7=e,x^{-1}ax=a^2$. For instance $(xa)(xa^2)=x(ax)a^2=x(xa^2)a^2=x^2a^4$. The reader can verify that one obtains, in this way, a non-abelian group of order $21$.

What is the symbol $x$?
From which algebraic system did this symbol $x$ come?
What is the product of $x$ and $a$?
Please tell me what the author wants to say.

Comment: Are you familiar with free groups? If so, the group the author is defining would just be the free group generated by ${a,x}$ modulo $a^7$, $x^3$, etc. to get all of the relations.

Comment: @AdamFrench Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although correct, this passage in the book is confusing. I remember being annoyed by this example when I was reading the book for the first time.

What Herstein shows is a special case of a certain construction of groups. So with a group $G$ and a suitable automorphism $\phi$ of $G$, you can construct a new group $H = \langle G, x \rangle$, where $G \trianglelefteq H$ and conjugation by $x$ acts on $G$ like $\phi$ does.

At this point in the book it would be difficult/cumbersome for Herstein to give all the necessary context and details for this construction. I would not worry about it too much and just keep reading. Honestly if someone is using the book to learn about groups for the first time, I think the way this example is presented is not so helpful.

The symbol $x$ is just a ''formal symbol''. It does not come from any algebraic system, you just pick something outside of $G$ then call it $x$. Then you define a multiplication on the set of symbols $\{x^i a^j\}$, subject to the rules $x^3 = a^7 = e, x^{-1}ax = a^2$. (Then the product of $x$ and $a$ is just $xa$, there is no other way to describe it.)

This is missing some details of course. Why would this multiplication be well defined? Why is it associative? What are the inverses?

Some context:

- More generally, suppose you have a group $G$ and an automorphism $\phi$ of $G$. Then with the same construction, you can construct a group $H = \langle G, x \rangle$, where $x$ is a formal symbol and we define multiplication such that $x^{-1}gx = \phi(g)$ for all $g \in G$. In this case $H = \{gx^i : g \in G, i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Moreover we construct $H$ such that $\langle x \rangle \cap G = \{e\}$.
- This construction is a semidirect product $G \rtimes \langle \phi \rangle$, which is a subgroup of the holomorph $G \rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(G)$. For more details look up terms like ''semidirect product'', ''external semidirect product'', ''holomorph'' in a textbook.
- Alternatively what Herstein constructs is the following group with generators and relations: $$\langle a,x : x^3 = a^7 = 1, x^{-1}ax = a^2 \rangle.$$ Look up ''free groups'', ''generators and relations'' in a textbook.

Comment: spin, thank you very much for your answer. I will skip this passage in Herstein's book.

Answer (score 5):

I hate descriptions of a group like that in Herstein, because it is not at all obvious to a newcomer that there might not be some secret collapsing of everything into the identity element. How do you know you can just "declare" when two things are equal without creating some kind of inconsistency somewhere?

What Herstein is aiming to do looks like describing a group by generators and relations, but typically the most you can get from such a description alone is an upper bound on the size of the group, but to know the description is really a group of order $21$ you need to put in some work. To understand what I'm getting at, the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023341/presentation-langle-x-y-z-mid-xyx-1y-2-yzy-1z-2-zxz-1x-2-ran) gives a description of a group with 3 generators and a few relations that turns out to be the trivial group after some fairly nontrivial work.

Instead of trying to make sense of what Herstein is doing, let's instead just *build* ourselves a nonabelian group of order $21$ using  $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in $\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z$.

In the group $(\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z)^\times$, the subgroup of order $3$ is $\{1,2,4 \bmod 7\} = \{b \bmod 7 : b^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 7\}$.
Let $G = \{(\begin{smallmatrix}b&c\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}) \bmod 7 : b^3 = 1 \}$. The upper right entries of matrices in $G$ are arbitrary integers modulo $7$ while the upper left entries are restricted to be the elements of $(\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z)^\times$ with order dividing $3$, and those are the powers of $2 \bmod 7$. As a *set*, $G$ has size $21$: $3$ options for the upper left entry and $7$ options for the upper right entry, and they can be picked arbitrarily.

Check $G$ is a closed under matix multiplication and inversion, so $G$ is a group of order $21$.  In $G$, let $a = (\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix})$ and $x = (\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix})$. Then $a$ has order $7$, $x$ has order $3$, and $xax^{-1} = (\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}) = a^2$.
In particular, $a$ and $x$ do not commute (since $xax^{-1} = a^2$ and $a^2 \not= a$), so $G$ is nonabelian.
A general element of $G$ looks like
$(\begin{smallmatrix}2^i&j\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}) = 
(\begin{smallmatrix}1&j\\0&1\end{smallmatrix})
(\begin{smallmatrix}2^i&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}) = 
(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix})^j
(\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix})^i = a^jx^i.
$ Herstein writes elements of his $G$ in the form $x^ia^j$. As $i$ and $j$ vary, the set of all $a^jx^i$ equals the set of all $x^ia^j$ since every element of $G$ is the inverse of something in $G$ and $(a^jx^i)^{-1} = x^{-i}a^{-j}$.

A similar construction gives you a nonabelian group of order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes such that $q \equiv 1 \bmod p$. See the top of page 5 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cauchyapp.pdf). You are looking at the case $p = 3$ and $q = 7$.

Comment: Herstein is not building the group as the quotient of a free group, so the issue here is not with whether some elements collapse to the identity. As a starting point Herstein takes the set $H = \{x^i a^j \}$, where $i \in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $j \in \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$. The rules $x^3 = a^7 = 1$, $x^{-1}ax = a^2$ determine the multiplication on $H$ uniquely. So you define $(x^i a^j) (x^{i'} a^{j'}) = (x^{i''} a^{j''})$ where $i''$ and $j''$ are determined by these rules. What is left to the reader is to check that this is associative, has identity, inverses, etc.

Comment: But I wish it were written more clearly and explicitly, I also dislike this part in the book. Basically to me the construction in the question is the construction of an external semidirect product.

Comment: @spin I understand that Herstein is just putting a nonobvious group law on the product set $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z$, but the way he describes it is super confusing to a student first learning group theory. I think he should have described the group directly on that product set of order $21$ instead of introducing irrelevant "symbols" $a$ and $x$.  What he writes gives the *impression* of looking like generators and relations, so that's why I wrote the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree. With a paragraph or two it could have been defined precisely, now it's just lazy writing. When I was first learning group theory, Topics in Algebra was one of the books I used. This example was very annoying and confusing, and raises many questions for someone learning about groups for the first time. "What do you mean formal symbols? Why can we formally subject $x$ to these conditions? Why can we multiply the elements with these rules? Is it supposed to be obvious that this is a group?" etc.

Comment: KCd, thank you very much for your answer and your construction.